# How to hide two cursors when some text is selected in UITextView?

Tags: ios, objective-c

When I set

```
textView.selectedRange =  NSMakeRange(0, 6);
```

It shows

[image]

How can I hide the two blue cursors?

Comment: ， and only hide the cursors? not selected blue back?

Comment: @aircraft only hide the cursors,blue back not change

Comment: you can not hide the cursor. If you want to hide it so you can tick editable option from storyboard.

Answer (score 0):

Sorry I don't think that changing the color or hiding just the caret is possible while retaining the `tintColor` of the selected text. The tint color determines the color of the cursor. Like the image shown below.

The green color tint makes the textView Cursor green too. If you make the cursor clear then text selection tint color would also be clear.
The code for changing the tint color is:

```
textView.tintColor = [UIColor greenColor];
```

[image]

You hide the cursor you also hide the text selection tint color.

Hope this helps.